Planck-scale measurements of sub-light-speed motion
Firstly, I want to make clear that I am not under the impression that the Planck scale represents a 'resolution' of physical reality, though I can understand why this question might make it seem that way. I am under the (possibly incorrect) impression that specifically the Planck time and Planck length represent the smallest measurable time/distance respectively, and that the ratio of the Planck length to the Planck time is the speed of light.
That being the case, consider the following setup- there is an object moving at some speed v less than the speed of light, whose position can be measured relative to its initial position at t = 0. After one Plank time, its position is measured again, as a distance between its current and initial positions. What result is expected?
I can think of three different ways this could go:

The Plank length acts as a proper 'resolution' of the distance measurement, so that if for example v = c/2, the measured distance is 0 after one Planck time, 1 Planck length after two or three Planck times, and so on.

Measuring the distance acts like your typical 'collapsing a wave function' observation, and you get something like the result that the object appears to move one Planck length per unit Planck time with probability equal to v as a fraction of c.

It is not possible to both measure the time precisely enough to know it's one Planck time later and the distance at the Planck scale, perhaps due to some Uncertainty Principle (note that in this setup you are not directly measuring v and position at the same time, which is forbidden by Heisenberg's).


Are any of these three correct? Is there a different expected result? Or is there a reason that this thought experiment simply breaks down completely that I haven't realized?

the ratio of the Planck length to the Planck time is the speed of light You’re correct about that.

We have no idea about how physics works at the Planck scale. Any answer to this question would be tremendously speculative.
